# How to create an OCSP request and validate response using Azure APIM?

Tags: xml, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-appservice, ocsp

As recommended [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789789/how-do-i-store-known-client-certificates-for-an-http-triggered-azure-function/66789932#66789932), I am toying with enabling Azure API Management (APIM) as a way to reduce unwanted traffic to an HTTP-triggered Azure Function.

The idea is to use APIM as a means to force the endpoint server (managed by Microsoft) to reject unknown requests (those not in the APIM "Trust Store" (for lack of a proper term)) before they are forwarded to the Function's application code.

In the [APIM docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/control-authentication-with-apim/4-secure-access-client-certs), there are examples of checking the client-cert thumbprint, issuer and subject, but no examples of creating an OCSP request and validating the response to show the client-cert has not been revoked.

I am already handling this in the application code, but don't want to split client-cert validation logic between APIM and the app code. Needs to be all handled in APIM.

**How do I use the APIM xml syntax to generate an OCSP request and decode its response to determine cert revocation status?**

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no knowledge nor ever used Azure APIM

OCSP requests have their downsides ([quick google search result](https://medium.com/@alexeysamoshkin/how-ssl-certificate-revocation-is-broken-in-practice-af3b63b9cb3#:%7E:text=Online%20Certificate%20Status%20Protocol%20(OCSP)&text=Still%2C%20it%20suffers%20from%20many,Prone%20to%20availability%20problems.)), which might be a reason to not allow or not to implement them.

My naive question in return would be:
Is it easy for you to update the "Trust store" in a timely manner. Is it therefore feasible to *also* update the APIM settings when you revoke a certificate?