# Type of Client-Cert to upload to Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, client-certificates

I have an HTTP-triggered Azure Function fronted with Azure API Management (APIM).

- Client-certificates are set to `Require` at the Azure **Function** level:

[image]

- **And** at the **APIM** level:

[image]

I need to add client-certificates (*public* client-certificates) to a "Trust Store" of some sort. It appears the "Client Certificate" page of APIM is equivalent to a Trust Store.

[image]

**Question is: What type of client-certificate is APIM looking for here?**

- *Should* just be the clients **public** certificate, right?
- I should not have to store these in Azure Key Vault as they do not contain private keys
- I just need to check whether the client-certificate in the request is from a "Trusted Source" to prevent requests from reaching my application code if they are unknown clients.

Comment: Did you get any progress? And if you felt my answer helpful to you, pls mark it as the answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this doc](https://aztoso.com/apim/client-certificates-authentication/) have a vivid explanation of enable client-certificate authentication in azure apim. To sum up here is that you don't have to upload the certificate file because you can set the `Thumbprint` in the policy with a value like

```
<when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null 
       || context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint != "456AAB1833DF842152605DF6C2B1DB2BBA29380D"
       || context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter<DateTime.Now)">
```

And if you upload the certificate, you can set the policy like this:

```
<when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null 
       || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint)
       || context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter<DateTime.Now)">
```

Here's a related [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients) on apim client-certificate.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my questions of: "What type of certificate is APIM looking for here?" and "Should just be the clients public certificate, right?". Reading the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates#prerequisites) it appears APIM wants me to get the client's PRIVATE certificates along with the password to access them. This makes no sense to me. I only want to compare certificate properties on the clients PUBLIC certificate and make an OCSP request to see if the cert is revoked before forwarding the request to my app code.

Comment: I have no further ideas here, sorry for it :(

Comment: did you get answer to your question- What type of certificate is APIM looking for here?. I am also looking for this info. Seems it requires private cert. But what if we want to authenticate clients which are sending public cert . One option is to just compare the thumbprint. But if I want to refer to APIM store, that will require private cert.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload a self signed public certificate(.cer) to APIM. Choose *custom* and leave the *password* field empty while adding the certificate.

[image]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates#prerequisites)

When you add self signed certificate, also install trusted root and intermediate CA certificates in your API Management instance. Finally, please disable chain certificate validation to avoid HTTP 500 errors while communicating with backend system.